# How can we Adjust image like instagram in edit feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-editing

i want to add the image adjustment feature in my app like Instagram.
For example: (straighten, Horizontal perspective, vertical perspective). i did so much R&D on that but i am not able to find the exact solution. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor 
Try this . This has much to meet ur requirements regarding the processing part.

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta Thanks, but there has not the perticular feature which i mention in the question.